# unable to get text from image using pytesseract

Tags: python

While I'm using below code , getting Error as "WindowsError:[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified". Please help me to get text from image.

```
from pytesseract import image_to_string
from PIL import Image

print image_to_string(Image.open(r'D:\\name.jpg'),lang='eng')
```

ERROR:

> WindowsError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         2 from PIL import Image
>         3 
>   ----> 4 print image_to_string(Image.open(r'D:\name.jpg'),lang='eng')
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.pyc
>   in image_to_string(image, lang, boxes, config)
>       120                                              lang=lang,
>       121                                              boxes=boxes,
>   --> 122                                              config=config)
>       123         if status:
>       124             errors = get_errors(error_string)
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.pyc
>   in run_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename_base, lang, boxes,
>   config)
>        44         command += shlex.split(config)
>        45 
>   ---> 46     proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>        47     status = proc.wait()
>        48     error_string = proc.stderr.read()
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.pyc in **init**(self, args,
>   bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds,
>   shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags)
>       388                                 p2cread, p2cwrite,
>       389                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
>   --> 390                                 errread, errwrite)
>       391         except Exception:
>       392             # Preserve original exception in case os.close raises.
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.pyc in _execute_child(self,
>   args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, cwd, env, universal_newlines,
>   startupinfo, creationflags, shell, to_close, p2cread, p2cwrite,
>   c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite)
>       638                                          env,
>       639                                          cwd,
>   --> 640                                          startupinfo)
>       641             except pywintypes.error, e:
>       642                 # Translate pywintypes.error to WindowsError, which is
>
> WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: to ask the obvious, are you sure there is a file in `D:\name.jpg`? Could you test to see if you can work with an image on your current folder instead of on `D:\`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installation of all package and Tesseract-OCR app, you should restart your PC. I tried your code and get the same problem but after restart my PC it worked for me. Please try.

Answer (score 2):

Install google tesseract-ocr from [tesseract-ocr](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tesseract-ocr-alt/files/). The code might miss dependencies.

Comment: Having error in installation .... and also why required third party software? @Bodhi

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to give the path as raw string.
Without raw string:

```
print image_to_string(Image.open('D:\\name.jpg'),lang='eng')
```

With raw string:

```
print image_to_string(Image.open(r'D:\name.jpg'),lang='eng')
```

Comment: Sorry Bodhi, I tried your code but still I'm getting same error.

Comment: How did you verify the file location ?

Comment: @Bodhi94: If you escape `\` as `\\`, you don't need to add `r`

Comment: When I'm using only "Image.open(r'D:\name.jpg')" code then my image opened successfully, but using of "image_to_string" function I am getting error.